# app.component.html Missing initializer in const declaration, routing error

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9

I added the following in *app.module.ts*

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const appRouter:Routes=[{
  path:'',component:HomeComponent
},{
  path:'users',component:UsersComponent
},{
  path:'servers',component:ServersComponent
}]
RouterModule.forRoot(appRouter)  -in imports array.
```

And in *app.component.html*

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And the error is

> app.component.html Missing initializer in const declaration, routing error

Can anybody resolve this issue as it says missing initializer in const declaration but it has already been initialized.

Comment: Have you import components which used in the routes?

Comment: Show us the full code of the router module class please ( ...const appRouter:Routes=[{...).

Comment: Please confirm apps bootstrap component (in `app.module`)

Comment: Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Without the full code, it's difficult to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component';
import { UserComponent } from './users/user/user.component';
import { EditServerComponent } from './servers/edit-server/edit-server.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './servers/server/server.component';
import { ServersService } from './servers/servers.service';
const appRouter:Routes=[{
  path:'',component:HomeComponent
},{
  path:'users',component:UsersComponent
},{
  path:'servers',component:ServersComponent
}]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    ServersComponent,
    UserComponent,
    EditServerComponent,
    ServerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRouter)
  ],
  providers: [ServersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
1.Add exports[appRoutes] in you routes.
I leave you a [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-outlets?file=app%2Fapp.routing.ts),You can upload your code in a repository, that would be helpful.